# handling rails timezone in several users namespaces, also how does around_action works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, timezone

I have a rails app with several namaspaces such as user, management, admin. which means I have current_user, current_management, current_admin.

1. How should I handle timezone settings for these different user namespaces. I read this (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones) but it shows current_user. What should I do with current_management ?
2. what does "around_action" actually do in this context ? if the user updates the timezone, what happens, or is there something i should set explicitly ?
3. when I display the time, should i always do in_time_zone ? if I need to do that why have the application controller code ?

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones

here is a code it request to put in application controller

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
around_action :set_time_zone, if: :current_user

private

def set_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

it says to display in current time zone like this

```
<%= time.in_time_zone(current_user.time_zone) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Can't you just use `current_management.time_zone` instead?
2. `around_action` will pass the execution block to `Time.use_zone`, changing the timezone inside the controller's action and views, but not on the outside.
3. You don't have to use `around_action` if you use `in_time_zone` (and vice versa). This will convert the time object to a given timezone. I believe `in_time_zone` is a safer solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer. so around_action will cause the whole app to use the timezone ? so on every display I will have to use in_time_zone ? I actually did like this (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ea8dd867c8ccb2c802470a01858e014) and i think it worked but not sure the sideeffects of this since i am running on my own one user, havent tried the effects of multiple users

Comment: @Axil `around_action` only affects the controller code and views and everything that is called within. It does not change the timezone for the whole app globally. You don't have to use `in_time_zone` if you use `Time.use_zone` for database objects, as active record will convert them to the current timezone.